# How can I specify the location of `.text` section in memory in NASM?

Tags: assembly, nasm, loader

In NASM, I can place code in `.text` simply by prefacing it with `section .text`.  How can I tell it where I want the `.text` section to start in vaddr space? E.g. I'd like it to be at 0x401000.

(Target is elf64.)

Note that NASM doesn't seem to support an `ORIGIN` or `ORG` directive for ELF files.

Comment: Either with org or with the linker?

Comment: With the linker, yes. E.g. `ld -Ttext=0x401000`.

Comment: NASM only assembles to ELF relocatable object files, not to executables directly; that's why it doesn't support `org`.  i.e. it doesn't incorporate an ELF linker, the way it does for the near-trivial case of a flat binary.  And ELF `.o` object files aren't yet nailed down to an absolute address; AFAIK there's no ELF metadata NASM could use to support `org` even if it wanted to.

Comment: @Jester Better: write a linker script.